# Hive JDBC connection giving NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

I am trying to create a connection and getMataData() for my local hive server instance (thrift).

Following is the code I am trying:

```
Class cl = Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default", "", "");
DatabaseMetaData data = conn.getMetaData();
System.out.println(data.toString());
```

But I am getting following Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/MetaException    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)  at
>   my.work.DataSourceConnectionCheck.checkHiveConnection(DataSourceConnectionCheck.java:23)
>     at
>   my.work.DataSourceConnectionCheck.main(DataSourceConnectionCheck.java:67)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     ... 5 more

Can any one please let me know which jar I missed?

Comment: do you have the hive-jdbc.jar in classpath?

Comment: Yes, I have hive-jdbc.jar in classpath.

Comment: actually org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException.class belongs to hive-metastore.jar ensure it is in your classpath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException` class is in the `hive-metastore` jar file